# join 2 mdx queries into one table

Tags: mdx

I need to merge the result 2 queries into one table. Queries are similar except one of WHERE conditions.
As far as I was able to find out while googling it is impossible to do as MDX have internal connections in database design.

I have tried to use this way: [Merge 2 MDX queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34232013/merge-2-mdx-queries)
But it turns out that in 1 hour I get this error:
XML for Analysis parser: The XML for Analysis request timed out before it was completed.

I have tried to make new members like that:

```
    member new_A AS
        aggregate
        (
            K
            ,
            A
        )
```

And then

```
select { new_A, ...
```

```
select { A , B , C , D } on 0,
non empty { Y * Z } on 1
from X
where (except(K), L, M, N, P);

select { A , B , C , D } on 0,
non empty { Y * Z } on 1
from X
where (K, L, M, N, P);
```

What I need to get in the end is a table that contains values of elements A,B,C,D as columns for condition K only and for all except condition K just next to it. it can be either A, new_A, B, new_B, etc or A, B, C, D , new_A, new_B, etc.

P.S. database is extremely big and the faster it works the better :)

Answer (score 0):

So i have tried to map your problem to AdventureWorks sample database. 
In my problem i am trying report [internet Sales Amount] for some countries for a set of subcategories. Then I edit my query to report all subcategories except "Road Bikes" in main columns and for road bikes i use measures.RoadBikes.

Query 1

```
with member
measures.RoadBikes
as 
( ([Product].[Subcategory].&[2],[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]))

select 
non empty
{
({[Customer].[Country].&[Australia],[Customer].[Country].&[Canada],[Customer].[Country].&[France],[Customer].[Country].&[United Kingdom],[Customer].[Country].&[United States]},
[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
),
({[Customer].[Country].&[Australia],[Customer].[Country].&[Canada],[Customer].[Country].&[France],[Customer].[Country].&[United Kingdom],[Customer].[Country].&[United States]},
measures.RoadBikes
)
}

on columns,
non empty
[Date].[Month of Year].[Month of Year]
on 
rows
from
[Adventure Works]
where 
({[Product].[Subcategory].&[31],[Product].[Subcategory].&[1],[Product].[Subcategory].&[2],[Product].[Subcategory].&[37],[Product].[Subcategory].&[3]})
```

Result

[image]

Edit the query

```
with member measures.UsRoadBikes as ([Product].[Subcategory].&[2],[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount])
select non empty
{({[Customer].[Country].&[Australia],[Customer].[Country].&[Canada],[Customer].[Country].&[France],[Customer].[Country].&[United Kingdom],[Customer].[Country].&[United States]},
[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount])}
on columns,
non empty
({[Product].[Subcategory].&[31],[Product].[Subcategory].&[1],[Product].[Subcategory].&[2],[Product].[Subcategory].&[37],[Product].[Subcategory].&[3]},
[Date].[Month of Year].[Month of Year]
) on rows
from [Adventure Works]
```

Result

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone!
It was decided to run queries in parallel to speed up.
Return data to be populated into dataset and then Linq to be used to work with it.